# Two Hudson Masters on the same Windows Server

Tags: windows, hudson, jenkins

I want to setup two Hudson Masters on the same Hardware. This will make administering Hudson easier, since both servers are used by two different (and independent) teams.

So far I tried to install one server as a service. I verified the installation and it is running ok. I than copied the installation into another path and changed the service information (different service Name and description) and the httpPort. I then create the service, once using `sc.exe create` and once using `hudson.exe install`. In both cases the server started. However, the configuration page acted goofy. So this approach is either not working at all or I missed another configuration file.

Does anyone has an idea how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried the same approach as documented in the question but avoided the copying of the original installation. So I created two folders and put a copy of hudson.war in it. Then I performed the following steps for both folders.

1. Start Hudson with `java -jar hudson.war`
2. Installed Hudson as a service using the web UI
3. went into the Hudson Base Dir and ran `hudson uninstall`
4. modified the port and the Service information in hudson.xml
5. installed the service through command line `hudson install`

Now I have two services and the first quick test looks promising.

Comment: I did some additional testing and also updated one of the instances. All my test are passed and I am happy with this solution.

Answer (score 2):

May I suggest:

1. run two instances of Tomcat
2. have each Tomcat running on its own HTTP port
3. deploy HUDSON.WAR in each Tomcat
4. set CATALINA_OPTS for each Tomcat to point to a different HUDSON_HOME

Comment: I was thinking of such a solution too. Right now, tomcat is not an approved software and therefore currently not an option. However, we have a different app server that we could use, but not on this hardware.

Long story short. Current option is to either get Hudson running with the buildin winstone or put both teams on the same server.